# Proper landing on pad?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I cannot seem to land properly on a station with just pads.  I fly in with landing gear extracted, the pad icon is blue and high freq beeps. I have to fly out cancel docking and try again. Often the 2nd time I can dock without issues.  Is it some bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many players claim the system is still buggy. I have encountered an issue with docking only once or twice since release, to be honest, so I'm reluctant to believe it. There are a lot of quirks with docking, though.

Are you sure you are facing the right direction? This is the north-side, which can be determined by looking at the physical launch pad. Most will have a mini control tower, which your nose should be facing. On your docking interface, your nose should be facing away from you.

As long as my nose is pointed in the right direction, I rarely encounter any trouble. I can usually land askew, slamming into the station as I thrust down.

Comment: Did not know i had to face North,  explains why it only happens on landing pads as internal dock aligns one automatically.

Comment: A common problem, glad I could help!